# Why do these `const int main=0xc3` (or other number) programs return 252 on OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, signals, x86-64, opcode

I heard about the "shortest C program that results in an illegal instruction": `const main=6;` for x86-64 over [on codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/shortest-code-to-throw-sigill/100557#100557) and it got me curious what would happen if I put different numbers there.

Now I guess this has to do with what is or isn't a valid x86-64 instruction (durr) but specifically I'd like to know what the different results mean.

- `const main=0` through `2` give bus error.
- `const main=3` gives a segfault.
- `6` and `7` give illegal instruction.

I get various bus errors and segfaults and illegal instructions up until 
`const main=194` which didn't give me an interrupt at all (at least not that got through to my python script that was generating these little programs).

**There are a few other numbers that also do not lead to exceptions/interrupts and thus to Unix signals. I checked the return code of a couple and the return code was `252`. I don't know why or what that means or how it got there.**

`204` got me a "trace trap". This is `0xcc` which I know is the `int3` interrupt - that's fun! (241/0xf1 also gets me this)

---

Anyway, it keeps going and it's obviously mostly bus errors and segfaults and a few illegal instructions here and there and the occasional... does whatever it does and then returns with 252...

I googled around some opcodes but I don't really know what I am doing or where to look to be honest. I haven't even looked at all my outputs yet just been scrolling through. I understand that a segfault is invalid access to valid memory and a bus error is access to invalid memory and I plan to look at the patterns of the numbers and work out where these are happening and why. But the 252 thing has me a bit stumped.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import time
import signal

os.mkdir("testc")
try:
    os.chdir("testc")
except:
    print("Could not change directory, exiting.")

for i in range(0, 65536):
    filename = "test" + str(i) + ".c"
    f = open(filename, "w")
    f.write("const main=" + str(i) + ";")
    f.close()
    outname = "test" + str(i)
    subprocess.Popen(["gcc", filename, "-o",  outname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    time.sleep(1)
    err = subprocess.Popen("./" + outname, shell=True)
    result = None
    while result is None:
        result = err.poll()
    r = result
    if result == -11:
        r = "segfault"
    if result == -10:
        r = "bus error"
    if result == -4:
        r = "illegal instruction"
    if result == -5:
        print = "trap"
    print("const main=" + str(hex(i)) + " : " + r)
```

**This produces a C program in `testc/test20.c` like**

```
const int main=20;
```

Then compiles it with `gcc` and runs it.  (And sleeps for 1 second before trying the next number.)

There were no expectations. I just wanted to see what happened.

Comment: You do realise that none of those programs are actually *valid,* yes?

Comment: Why not write your test in C ?

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes, he clearly does. He's just curious about the different ways that the program fails.

Comment: A positive value is the process's exit status, as in `exit(252)`. I guess what you're seeing has something to do with the way the process returns this to the parent.

Comment: Note that what your invalid programs do depends on what other data is in the memory after your "main".  Try running the programs with a debugger and step through the assembly instructions.

Comment: Or to put it another way, your programs are 100%  Undefined Behavior, and trying to draw any conclusions at C level is futile. You really need to look at the assembly code.

Comment: Why do you show us your python-stuff if you ask about C? Showing us the created C code would be more useful.

Comment: @hyde ah yeah, I am installing gdb now to have a look (this is your brain on insomnia) - if it is undefined though, why does it appear to be the same all the time? I guess most of what is in memory is zeros with lots of junk here and there so probabilistically you hit a zero more often than not? Obviously I could be wrong though lol - I might look at that too, just malloc some chunks and look and see what is there.

Comment: OK got why these two specifically behave that way. 0xc2 and 0xc3 seem to be retq. I still don't know why they return 252 though. I assume it's in the return register (is that rax?) but I don't know why.

Comment: The next one that is out of the pattern is 0x4cd which leads to -8. Having looked at the assembly the non segfault/bus error/sigill ones are fairly predictable (they end in retq or trap) although as the numbers get longer more stuff is going infront so maybe that will change once we get a full byte or two in front? Working out the pattern behind the bus error vs segfault is my next plan.

Comment: Although thinking about it does the fact it's little endian mean that it won't make a difference what comes "before" it (because it actually comes after the retq?)

Comment: Since you get a bus error,are you on BSD(like OS/X?) I ask because it depends on the OS(and the calling convention). On x86 systems generally the value in EAX is the return value from a ret instruction. Only the lower byte in AL will be returned to the shell. Since EAX isn't set by your code, it is whatever value was in EAX prior to the C runtime calling main.

Comment: This all falls into the realm of undefined behavior. But if you do `const char main[]={0xb0, 0x01, 0xc3};` the second byte is the return value. So you might be lucky enough to get 1 returned. The sequence of 3 bytes does `mov al, 1` `ret` .If you change the second byte it should alter the return code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks, yeah I've been messing about with the values and trying to make it make something that does something (so far I've just moved stuff to registers and then returned). This is fun though, I feel like I am learning from it even though it is a monumentally silly way to go about it and I should probably just read a book! And yes MacOS.

Comment: @SWilliams *"if it is undefined though, why does it appear to be the same all the time?"*, well, as said, to know that, you need to look at the generated assembly. Does it behave the same every time? Note that the assembly might change if you change compiler options, or if you re-arrange code, or if you upgrade your compiler toolchain, or according to the phase of the moon, or... so looking at result of one compilation is no guarantee it will be the same after next build.

Comment: *I understand that a segfault is invalid access to valid memory and a bus error is access to invalid memory* No, usually you get a segfault for trying to access an unmapped page.  x86-64 Linux doesn't normally give you a bus error for anything (so you're probably on something else, like OS X).  A bus error for misaligned SSE loads/stores would make sense.  x86-64 Linux will SIGBUS if you turn on x86 alignment checking (the AC flag in EFLAGS): [Debugging SIGBUS on x86 Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2089240).  But nobody does that because library funcs like memcpy use unaligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`int main = 194` is `c2 00 00 00`, which decodes as [`ret 0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret)**

**Whatever called `main` must have left 252 in the low byte of RAX**.  (The calling convention says that RAX is the return-value register, but it's not an arg-passing register so on function entry it holds whatever tmp garbage your caller was using it for.)

See the bottom of the answer for a theory on why you get SIGBUS for 2 but SIGSEGV for 3:  **I think RAX is a valid pointer on entry to main** (by chance of what the dynamic linker had there), `03 00 add eax, [rax]` destroys it but `02 00 add al, [rax]` doesn't, and then execution either faults on the `00 00  add [rax], al` from the next 2 bytes of `main`, or runs the `00 00` instruction and then falls off the end of a page.

[Update from @MichaelPetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54338079/why-do-these-const-int-main-0xc3-or-other-number-programs-return-252-on-os-x/54351012?noredirect=1#comment95523494_54351012): **RAX is *pointing to `main`* (in the read-only TEXT segment), and stores to read-only pages also SIGBUS.**  So `00 00  add [rax], al` will SIGBUS for that reason if RAX is still pointing there.

(Beware that this answer has some wrong guesses and wasn't fully rewritten every time I got new info from @SWilliams or @MichaelPetch.  The bullet points about what kinds of `#PF` cause which signal are up to date, and I've tried to at least add a correction after things that weren't quite accurate.  I think there's some value to the wrong theories, as an illustration of others kinds of things that *might* have happened, so I'm leaving it all in here.)

---

Your Python program fails on my Linux machine  once it gets to `c2 00 00 00` `ret imm16`, the first one that returns successfully.  (On Linux, the `.rodata` section ends up *after* `.text` [in the TEXT segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format), so there's nothing for `main` to fall into.)

```
...
const main=0xc0 : segfault
const main=0xc1 : segfault
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./opcode-test.py", line 34, in <module>
    print("const main=" + str(hex(i)) + " : " + r)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Doesn't python have an equivalent of [`strsignal(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsignal) to map signals to standard text strings like "Illegal instruction"?  (Like `strerror` but for signal codes instead of errno values?)

---

**Most x86 instructions are multiple bytes long**.  x86 is little-endian, so you're mostly looking at
`?? 00 00 00 90 90 90 ...` or for larger integers `?? ?? 00 00 90 90 90 90 ...`, assuming your linker fills bytes between functions with `0x90  nop` like GNU `ld` on Linux does.

These byte sequences might decode to one or more valid instructions before you hit the NOPs and fall through to whatever CRT function the linker puts after `main`.  If you get there without faulting, and without offsetting the stack pointer, you've entered the function with a valid return address on the stack (`main`'s caller, another CRT function) exactly like if main tail-called it.

Presumably that function returns 252 (or some wider value whose low byte is 252).  Returning from `main` leads to clean process exit, making an exit system call with `main`'s return value.

This fall-through tailcall is like if main ended with `return next_function(argc, argv);`.

---

#### **Correction** (without rewriting the whole answer, sorry)

**Since `main=194` is the first one that worked**, I think you're not actually getting fall-through, probably only C2 `ret imm16` and C3 `ret` are leading to a clean exit.  And for `c2`, it has to be followed by 2 `00` bytes, or else it'll break the stack for `main`'s caller.

**Or those instructions with a prefix that doesn't do anything, or a harmless one-byte instruction**.  e.g. `90 nop` / `c3 ret` or `90 nop` / `c2 00 00 ret 0`.  Or `91 xchg eax, ecx`, etc. could actually give you a different return value, swapping EAX with another register.  (x86 dedicates opcodes `90 .. 97` to xchg-with-EAX, because on original 8086 AX was more "special", without instructions like `movsx` to sign-extend into other registers.  And without 2 operand `imul`.

**Other harmless one-byte instructions include `99 cdq` and `98 cwde`, but not `push` or `pop`** (because changing RSP would make it not point at the return address).  Some one-byte flag set/clear instructions are `f9 stc`, `fd std`, but not `fb sti` (that's privileged, unlike the carry flag and direction flag).

**Harmless prefixes are `0x40..4f` REX prefixes, 0xf2`/`f3`REP, and`0x66`and`0x67` operand-size and address size.  Also any segment-override prefixes might also be harmless.**

I just tested `main=0xc366` and `main=0xc367` and yes they both exit cleanly.  GDB decodes `66 c3` as `retw` (operand-size prefix) and `67 c3` as `addr32 ret` (address size prefix), but both still pop a 64-bit return address, and don't truncate the stack pointer either.  (I took out the `-no-pie` I'd been using, so RIP was outside the low 32 bits along with RSP).

---

Note that `00` is the opcode for `add [r/m8], r8`, so **`00 00` decodes as `add [rax], al`**.

To get past those `00` bytes and get to the "nop sled" the linker inserts as padding, **you need the opcode (and modrm byte if the opcode uses one) to encode the start of a longer instruction**, like [`0xb8   mov eax, imm32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) which is 5 bytes long, and consumes the next 4 bytes after the `0xb8`.  In fact there are short-form mov-immediate encodings for every register, so `0xb8 + 0..7` will all get you past the gap.  Except for `mov esp, imm32`, which will lead to a crash once you get to the next function because it stepped on the stack pointer.

One of the early ones is `05`, the short-form (no modrm) opcode for [`add eax, imm32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html).  Most original-8086 ALU instructions have a special AX,imm16 / EAX,imm32 short form, instead of the `op  r/m32, imm32` or `imm8` form that uses a ModRM byte to encode the destination operand.  (And the bits of the `/r` field in ModRM as extra opcode bits.)

**See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code) for more about AL / EAX / RAX short form encodings, and one byte instructions.**

For manually decoding x86 machine code, see Intel's manuals, especially the vol.2 manual which details the instruction encoding formats, and has an opcode table at the end.  (See links [in the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)). **For just an opcode map, see http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html.**

---

#### Use a disassembler or debugger to see what's in your executables

**But really, use a disassembler like** `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.    Or `llvm-objdump`.  Find `main` in the output, and look at what you get.  (Or use GDB, because labels in the middle of an instruction throw off the disassembler.)

**Use `objdump -rwC -Mintel  -D -j .rodata -j .text testc/test194`** to get output like this, disassembling the .text and .rodata sections as code:

```
testc/test194:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400540 <__libc_csu_init>:
  400540:       41 57                   push   r15
  400542:       49 89 d7                mov    r15,rdx
  ...
  4005a4:       c3                      ret    
  4005a5:       90                      nop
  4005a6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00   nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]

00000000004005b0 <__libc_csu_fini>:
  4005b0:       c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00000000004005c0 <_IO_stdin_used>:     ;;;; This is actually data!
  4005c0:       01 00                   add    DWORD PTR [rax],eax
  4005c2:       02 00                   add    al,BYTE PTR [rax]

00000000004005c4 <main>:
  4005c4:       c2 00 00                ret    0x0
        ...             ; objdump elided the last 0, not me.  It literally put ...
```

(I modified your python script to add the `-no-pie` gcc option, which is why my disassembly has absolute addresses, instead of just small addresses relative to the start of the file = 0.  I wondered if that might put `main` somewhere it could fall through, but it didn't.)

**Notice there's only a small gap between .text and .rodata.  They're part of the same ELF *segment* (in the ELF program headers that the OS's program loader looks at), so they're part of the same mapping, no unmapped pages between them.**  If we're lucky, the intervening bytes are even filled with `0x90 nop` instead of `00`.  Actually, something filled the gap between `__libc_csu_init` and `__libc_csu_fini` with long NOPs.  Maybe that was from the assembler if they were in the same source file.

`main` is of course in `.rodata` because you declared it in C as a read-only global (static storage), like `const int main = 6;`.  I you used `const int main __attribute__((section(".text"))) = 123`, you could get `main` in the normal `.text` section.  On my system, it ends up right before `__libc_csu_init`.

But labels interrupt disassembly; the disassembler thinks it must have been wrong and restarts decoding from the label.  So in GDB on `testc/test5` (with `set disassembly-flavor intel` and `layout reg`, then using the `start` command to stop at the start of `main`), I'll get

```
   |0x40053c <main>                 add    eax,0x41000000                                                                                                 │
   │0x400541 <__libc_csu_init+1>    push   rdi                                                                                                            │
   │0x400542 <__libc_csu_init+2>    mov    r15,rdx
```

But from `objdump -drwC -Mintel` (disassembing only the `.text` section is the default for `-d`, and I used the GNU C attribute to put `main` there so my program could work the way yours does), I get:

```
000000000040053c <main>:
  40053c:       05 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000400540 <__libc_csu_init>:
  400540:       41 57                   push   r15
  400542:       49 89 d7                mov    r15,rdx
```

Notice that the `....` on the same line as the `05 00 00 00` indicates that decoding didn't get to the end of an instruction.

And since `main` isn't aligned by 16 here, it's right up against the start of `__libc_csu_init`.  So the `add eax, imm32` consumes the REX.W prefix (`41`) from `push r15`, making it decode as `push rdi` if reached by falling through from main instead of by a call to the `__libc_csu_init` label.

---

### The above output was from Linux.  Your OS X system would be different

OS X puts most of the CRT startup code in libc, not statically linked into the executable with `main`.

## Or maybe there isn't anything for your main to fall through into

If there was, `main=5` would have worked, but you say the first non-crashing result was with `main=194`, which is an actual `ret`.

If nothing before `c3 ret` or `c2 00 00  ret 0` returned, then probably there's nothing to fall into after `main`, or the gap isn't padded with repeated `90 nop` to form a "nop sled" that will execute ok if decoding starts anywhere in the middle of it.  (e.g. after an earlier instruction consumes the trailing `0` bytes at the end of the dword `int main`, and some of the padding bytes.)

---

> I understand that a segfault is invalid access to valid memory and a bus error is access to invalid memory

No, that simplified description is backwards.  Usually you get a segfault for trying to access an unmapped page, on all Unixes.  But you get a bus error for some kinds of invalid access (even on valid addresses).

Solaris on SPARC gives you a bus error for misaligned word loads/stores to valid memory.

On x86-64 Linux, you only get SIGBUS for really weird stuff.  See [Debugging SIGBUS on x86 Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089167/debugging-sigbus-on-x86-linux).  Non-canonical stack pointer leading to a `#SS` exception, reading past the end of a `mmap`ed file that was truncated.  Also if you enable x86 alignment checking (AC flag), but nobody does that because library funcs like memcpy use unaligned loads/stores, and compiler code-gen assumes that unaligned integer loads/stores are safe.

IDK what hardware exceptions *BSD maps to SIGBUS, but I'd assume that regular out-of-bounds access, like NULL-pointer dereference, would SIGSEGV.  That's pretty standard.

---

@MichaelPetch says in comments that **on OS X**

- `#PF` (page fault hardware exception) from code-fetch cases the kernel to deliver SIGBUS
- `#PF` from a data load/store to an unmapped page results in SIGSEGV.
- `#PF` from a store to a read-only page results in SIGBUS.  (And *this* is what's happening after `02 00 add al, [rax]`, in the `00 00 add [rax], al` that forms the 2nd byte of `main`.  The rest of this answer doesn't take this into account.)

(Of course this is after checking if the page-fault was due a difference between the hardware page table and the logical process memory map, e.g. from lazy mapping, copy-on-write, or pages paged out to disk.)

**So if your `int main` is landing at the very end of an unmapped page, `05   add eax,imm32` would read one extra byte past the end of the dword holding `int main`** (`.long 5` in GAS syntax asm).  **That would go into the next page and SIGBUS.**  (Your last comment indicates it does SIGBUS.)

#### A theory for what's going on with the first few values:

You report:

- a bus error for main = `02 00  add  al, [rax]`  / `00 00  add [rax], al
- but a segfault for main = `03 00   add  eax, [rax]` / `00 00  add [rax], al`.

We know the low byte of RAX is `252`, so if RAX holds a valid pointer value, it's 4-byte aligned.  So if loading a byte from `[rax]` works, so does loading a dword.

**So probably the memory-source `add` is succeeding**, and modifying AL, the low byte of RAX (byte operand size) probably still leaving RAX a valid pointer.**  Then if the rest of the page containing `main` is filled with   `00 00  add [rax], al` instructions (or just the one inside main itself), those will succeed (without further modifying RAX) until execution falls off into an unmapped page, as long as RAX is *still* a valid pointer after running whatever `main` decoded to.

Actually, the memory-destination `add` itself faults and raises SIGBUS.

**`03 00   add  eax, [rax]` writes EAX, and thus truncates RAX to 32-bit.**  (writing a 32-bit register implicitly zero-extends into the full 64-bit register, unlike writing low 8 or 16 partial registers.)  **This definitely gives you an invalid pointer**, because OS X maps static code/data outside the low 32 bits of virtual address space.
So **the following `00 00  add [rax], al` will definitely fault** from trying to write an out-of-bounds address, causing a `#PF` that raises SIGSEGV.

**There's probably *just* the one `00 00` from the last two bytes of `main` before the end of a page.**  Otherwise `05   add eax, imm32` would segfault from truncating RAX and then running `00 00 add [rax], al`.  For it to SIGBUS, it must code-fetch into an unmapped page without decoding any memory-access instructions after that.

There are certainly other plausible explanations for what you're seeing, but I think this explains all your observations so far; without more data we can't disprove it.  Obviously the easiest thing would be to fire up GDB or whatever other debugger and just `start` / `si` and watch what happens.

Comment: He already has said he is using MacOS when I made that inquiry about the bus error. His comment: _And yes MacOS_

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks.  I don't have a Mac, so that doesn't help me improve the answer by actually seeing how its linker lays out a binary. :/  I wrote most of it thinking there would be fall-through into the next function, but now I'm thinking maybe it's just `ret` and prefix+`ret` that are returning, like I was getting before I used an attribute to put `main` in the .text section.

Comment: That was really informative thanks. I don't have enough rep to vote but yeah enjoyed reading that. More to explore now. Should try playing around with some things in a linux vm too and look at differences.

Comment: In terms of this test code. The reason for the bus errors on MacOS is because the constant `main` is placed at the **end** of the  read only page (starting 4 bytes before the 4kb boundary). Anything that doesn't decode into a complete instruction will run into the next page which is not executable. If a complete instruction can be processed and it happens to do a memory access that doesn't have privilege to do so it will segfault.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: So MacOS sends SIGBUS instead of SIGSEGV for a page fault due to code-fetch instead of data load/store?  Or does it always SIGBUS for `#PF` on unmapped pages (in cases where it wasn't just lazy mapping)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: The OP reports a bus error for `02 00  add  al, [rax]`, but a segfault for `03 00   add  eax, [rax]`.  Possibly RAX was *pointing* near the end of a page, allowing the byte load to succeed?  No, but `252 = 256-4`, so it's 4-byte aligned.  Maybe it was the `00 00` instruction following that faulted?  The OP doesn't mention `05   add eax,imm32` (which would consume a 5th byte after `int main`).

Comment: That was bus error. Most results are. First 10 segfaults are const ```main=0x3 : segfault
const main=0xb : segfault
const main=0x13 : segfault
const main=0x1b : segfault
const main=0x23 : segfault
const main=0x2b : segfault
const main=0x33 : segfault
const main=0x41 : segfault
const main=0x43 : segfault
const main=0x45 : segfault```

Comment: @SWilliams: Then I think MichaelPetch is right that your `main` is ending up at the very end of a page, followed by an unmapped page.  I added a section that explains why `02` SIGBUSes while `03` SIGSEGVs.  Padding with `00` bytes after `main` until an unmapped page could have explained that, but `05 add eax, imm32` getting SIGBUS instead of SIGSEGV rules that out.  Use a debugger and single-step from the start of `main` if you want to see it in action.  Debuggers are vital tools for learning asm, and for checking guesswork by veterans :)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: thanks, I think everything makes sense now with `main` at the end of a page: If RAX was a valid pointer, `add eax, [rax]` destroys it but `add al, [rax]` doesn't.  Leading to `00 00 add [rax], al` faulting or falling through.  I think you deleted your comment confirming that OS X does SIGBUS for code fetch vs. SIGSEGV for data.  I updated my answer with details.

Comment: Ok, gonna have a go with lldb (tried to use gdb and it was all kinds of hoops to jump through to let it actually work on macOS because of SIP :/)

Comment: SIGBUS will occur when there is a page fault in a code fetch, but in MacOS you also get a SIGBUS when writing to read only memory. Writing/Reading from/to an unmapped page gives SIGSEV. When using `const main=2` it SIGBUSes because the value in RAX just so happens to be a pointer to main (0x100000FFC) ;-).So in this sequence `add al,BYTE PTR [rax]` `add    BYTE PTR [rax],al` the second instruction actually attempts to overwrite the code (itself) in a read only segment and gives SIGBUS.

Comment: When using `const main=3` you end up with `add    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]` (which computes to 0xFFF) followed by `add    BYTE PTR [rax],al` which then tries to write to the unmapped page at the beginning of memory so it SIGSEVs