# map shared memory size using mmap more than set size done by ftruncate

Tags: c, ubuntu, posix, shared-memory

i have few question based on below source:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int g;
int main(void) {
    int fd = shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(int)); // set size by sizeof(int)
    int *p1 = mmap(NULL, 10*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,0); //now map  10*sizeof(int).
    if (p1== MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("*****************error");
    }
    *p1 = mmap(NULL, 8*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,0);
    if (p1== MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("*****************error");
    }

    *p1=89;

    return g;
}
```

Question 1 :
why i don't see any error while i set size as size_of(int) and then map 10*size_of(int)

Question 2:
how many instace of shared mem is created here? i mean is there only one shared mem created or two as i did mmap twice?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be sure the first mmap return a valid address?

Comment: i think but may be i am wrong.

Comment: `mmap` returns `(void *)-1`  for failure.  So your error check cannot really capture the failure.  I was wondering what you got when you ran your code.

Comment: i have updated my source . I have checked error now for both.

Comment: Your second error check is ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int g;
int main(void) {
    int fd = shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(int)); // set size by sizeof(int)
    int *p1 = mmap(NULL, 10*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,0); //now map  10*sizeof(int).
    *p1 = mmap(NULL, 8*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,0);
    if (!p1){
        printf("*****************error");
    }
    *p1 = g;
    *p1=89;

    return g;
}
```

> Question 1 : why i don't see any error while i set size as size_of(int) and then map 10*size_of(int)

Because you don't check the return value from `mmap()`, you don't know if an error happened or not.  By immediately calling `mmap()` again with

```
*p1 = mmap(NULL, 8*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,0);
```

you mask any potential errors from the first `mmap()` call, and you also leak any memory that was successfully allocated.

> Question 2: how many instace of shared mem is created here? i mean is there only one shared mem created or two as i did mmap twice?

If the first call succeeded, you mapped two memory segments.  If it failed, you only mapped one if the second once succeeded.

If the first call did succeed, you leaked the memory.

Note that if you tried to write to the `mmap()`'d segment past the end of the size of the file you set with `ftruncate()`, you will not cause the file to grow.  Per [the POSIX `mmap()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html):

> Note that references beyond the end of the object do not extend the object as the new end cannot be determined precisely by most virtual memory hardware. Instead, the size can be directly manipulated by ftruncate().

On Linux, trying to access `mmap()`'d data beyond the end of the mapped file will likely result in your process [receiving a `SIGBUS` signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089167/debugging-sigbus-on-x86-linux).

Comment: actually it does not shows any error if i use if (p1== MAP_FAILED) {
  printf("*****************error");
 } after the first mmap also.

Comment: @EricIpsum If you change the code to detect failure and the check doesn't detect a failure, then the first `mmap()` worked.  But as originally posted, you didn't really know if the first `mmap()` call worked or not, although it most likely did.